# How to find the amount of characters in an input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help with finding the number of characters in an input tag and create an alert when there is a certain amount. Like if there are 25, then it creates an alert that says "Max". [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mox/tq2ocz1h/) is the fiddle that it is on. This is a little of what I have--

```
Char.innerText = $("#input:text").val().length;
```

This works fine for what I am using it for, but when I try to use `Char` in an `if` statement, it won't work.

Comment: Why can't you use `$("#input:text").val().length == 25` as a condition?

Comment: What in the jsfiddle isn't working precisely?

Comment: Probably because the contents of char are text, not an integer.  Also, if you put an alert() in a setInterval, you're not going to like the results if you do get it to work.  Try something like this:  https://jsfiddle.net/hrL0ea2k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the if statement in your keyup function:

```
if ($("#input:text").val().length == 25){
        alert("Too many characters.");
    }
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tq2ocz1h/6/)

EDIT: Luke just beat me to it, but there's where to put it in the JSfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this:

```
if ($("#input:text").val().length == 25) {
 alert('MAXXX');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Dave pointed out in the comments, you need to make sure you are comparing `Char.innerText` to a string since it is text.

Here is a valid `if` statement using `Char.innerText`:

```
if (Char.innerText == "25") {
  // alert
}
```

Alternatively, you can change `Char.innerText` to an integer and compare with 25.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach with an event and some alert and output. Limit is five charcters.

```js
function textCounter2(field, counter, maxlimit) {
    if (field.value.length > maxlimit) {
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
        alert('Max!');
    } else {
        document.getElementById(counter).innerText = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
}
```

```html
<input name="test" onkeyup="textCounter2(this, 'subtitlecount_lbl', 5)" onchange="textCounter2(this, 'subtitlecount_lbl', 5)" /><br />
<span id="subtitlecount_lbl"></span> characters left
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using the maxlength attribute for the input element why not compare against this value rather than hardcoding it into the if statement.

Also, rather than firing this on the keyup event which will also detect presses of the tab key or other non-printing control characters you should use the input event.

```
$('#input:text').on('input', function checkLength() {
  var max = this.getAttribute('maxlength');
  if (max && this.value.length == max) {
    alert('max length reached');
  }
});
```